Man accused of murdering child in US south, set free
This American movie takes place in the south I believe in the 40s or 50s. A child has been murdered and a (black?) man has been accused and arrested. 
One scene includes the victim's mother at a church service. In the middle of the sermon/message she stands up and begins to say it isn't "fair" or it isn't "right" that her boy was taken from her. She gets more upset and her husband escorts her out of the church.
Another scene is at the courthouse. The man is found not guilty and hugs his wife/child(ren) and says he will see them soon. As he is getting into the car, the victim's mother comes to speak to him but then shoots him. 
It is NOT "A Time To Kill" or "To Kill A Mockingbird" although it is very very similar to TKAM.

This sounds like Lady in White from 1988 with Lukas Haas, a horror film which mostly takes place in the early 60s about a boy encountering ghosts and a child murderer. In a subplot, a black janitor is blamed for the children's murders and in one scene, the mother of one of the victims stands up in church and asks why her boy wasn't spared. The janitor is later acquitted due to insufficient evidence; he hugs his wife as he exits the courthouse and gets into a car. The boy's mother then approaches the car and pretends to apologize for her behavior but then fatally shoots him.
Here's the trailer:




@Victoria No problem. Don't forget do close the question by clicking on the check mark (if you still can).
